# Should a Database Table Use the Identical Struct as Defined in the API?

Tags: database, api, go, architecture, grpc

Suppose I have a grpc service, and there is an API to create new user like this:

```
 service UserService{
  rpc CreateUser(CreateUserRequest) returns (CreateUserResponse);
}

message User {
  string userId = 1;
  string firstName = 2;
  string lastName = 3;
  string password = 4;
}
message CreateUserRequest {
  user User = 1;
}

message CreateUserResponse {
  user User = 1;
}
```

The service saves user data into a users_table in PostgresDb like this:

```
user1 := NewUser() // instantiating the User object as defined in the proto file.
// user2 := NewMyUser() // instantiating the MyUser object as defined separately in the service.
result := s.db.Table(UsersTable).Create(user1)
```

In addition, i'm using proto buffer to generate the server and client code based on the api proto file above.
My question is: When instantiating the user object, should the user be the generated User struct defined in the proto definition? or should I define another User struct as a model in the service dedicated for postgresDb like this?

```
struct MyUser {
      userId string
      firstName string 
      lastName  string 
      password string 
      createdAtMs int64 // an extra field not available in the api
}
```

Follow-up question:
What are the Pros and Cons of each approach? and what is the best design principle for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways happen in practice. It probably depends most on how much logic your service has; a service with very little logic (e.g., a small wrapper around a DB) is much more likely to store the proto directly in the database. It is very common to have similar-but-slightly-different protos where data is copied at each step as it passes through a system.

If you store a proto directly in the DB and then realize you made a mistake, you can "fork" the proto message by creating a new one that is compatible with the old one (a new name, but all the same fields with same ids). You have the pain of migrating your code to the new message (leaving the old one in your service), but with this approach you don't have to reencode all the data in your database before swapping to the new message type.

If you choose to use the same message in the DB, you should *make sure* to strip unknown fields before storing it. Otherwise when you add a new field in the future you may find a broken/malicious client already stored data in that field.